# Time machine backups getting corrupted

Tags: osx-lion, time-machine

About once a month, I get the following message for my time machine backup:

> Time Machine completed a verification of your backups. To improve reliability, Time Machine must create a new backup for you.

I'm guessing that this is because my backup was corrupted and needs to be redone.  This is annoying for 2 reasons:

1. I loose all of my old backups.
2. It takes several hours to recreate the backup.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is this common behavior for everyone using time machine?
2. How can I avoid this?

Could it be the case that closing your laptop during a backup will cause corruption?

Comment: No, that's not common. Closing the laptop should *ideally* just pause the backup and your MacBook will continue where it left off when you open it again – but I haven't tried that. I would probably start *verifying* the volume through Disk Utility and checking for errors. Also, try switching to another drive if possible (I know, might not be that easy).

Comment: I used diskutility on the backup disk.  All looks fine.  This is actually the second drive I am using.  It works fine for my wife.  The first drive also had problems (but I don't think they were related).

Comment: I'm also just wondering if I should give up on time machine.  See http://superuser.com/questions/440816/alternatives-to-time-machine

Answer (score 0):

Look at this blog post, it seems that it can solve this problem:
http://sansumbrella.com/writing/2012/the-reluctant-sysadmin-nas-time-machine/

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for contributing. The convention on Superuser is that you summarize instructions in your answer. Just providing a link without any explanation is frowned upon.

Comment: Better than nothing.  :-)  I'll try this out.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: And now the link is dead.