# Alternatives to Time Machine

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

I have been having trouble with time machine now for a long time.  I originally thought it was my network storage device, so I got a new one and the problems persist.  See my question here: [Time machine backups getting corrupted](https://superuser.com/questions/440370/time-machine-backups-getting-corrupted#comment509263_440370).

So, I am looking for a similar product that is more reliable.  My requirements are simple:

1. Must backup from a mac to a networked hard drive
2. Must be able to back up piecemeal (I want to be able to close my laptop during a backup with no bad effects).

Comment: We generally don't do product recommendations since these questions only end up in a list of answers all based on personal preference. Have you looked for "Time Machine alternatives" and tried some already? I personally like Carbon Copy Cloner, but I'm going to say that it's going to be hard to find something that fulfills your second requirement — only the cloud sync programs like Dropbox or Google Drive do this somewhat reliably.

Comment: I second the vote for [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) for a basic backup tasks.